# Como puedo cargar una imagen en formato "SVG", en el header.php de Wordpress Gutenberg?? -

Tags: php, css, wordpress, svg

Estimad@s

Su gentil ayuda, por favor, ya me he quebrado la cabeza intentando hayar una solucion al siguiente inconveniente.

El codigo a continuacion es del header de un proyecto de Wordpress, el cual en la parte de la carga de imagen, no la valida y no realiza la misma. Sin embargo cuando cambio el formato a cualquier otro, como "PNG", lo realiza sin ningun inconveniente.

Ya revise el tamaño de los formatos de las imagenes en "SVG", y los reduje al minimo posible y ni de esa forma se consigue subirlas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

   <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.1">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
       
       <!-- This fuction of wordpress inject the styles of CSS -->
       <?php wp_head(); ?>
   </head>
   <body>

   <header class="site_headerSty">

       <div class="container_generalSty ">
           <div class="site_navigationBarSty">
                
               <!-- In this part I try to load the Image Logo -->
                <!-- ========================================= -->

                 <div class="site_logoSty">     
                   <a href="<?php echo esc_url( site_url('/') ); ?>">
                       <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/dixi_logo_v4.svg" alt="Dixigunnpler"/>
                   </a>
               </div>
              <!-- ========================================= -->

               <?php 
                   $args = array
                       (
                           "theme_location"    => "main_menu",
                           "container"         => "nav",
                           "container_class"   => "main_menuSty"     
                       );
                   wp_nav_menu($args);
               ?>
           </div>
       </div> 
   </header>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, como mencione anteriormente permite la carga de imágenes en formato "PNG", su gentil ayuda para solventar esto, debido a que la imagen en demasiado grande, y se necesita poder redimensionarla sin afectar su resolución.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
           <!-- In this part I try to load the Image Logo -->
                <div class="site_logoSty">     
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( site_url('/') ); ?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/dixi.png" alt="Dixigunnpler"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!-- ======================================= -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usando la función `bloginfo` de esta forma:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/img/dixi_logo_v4.svg" alt="Dixigunnpler"/>
```

Comment: que tal. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. He intentado cambiarle el codigo de la imagen por el que tu me dices, pro igua, aun asi no se perciben cambios, no se carga todavia la imagen. Ya no se que mas hacerle.

Comment: Al inspeccionar esa parte, que te retorna, una url no valida?

Comment: Compañero, disculpa, como realizo esa consulta???, con un "var_dump"??. Y en que parte le haria.?

Comment: @Avellaneda solo ingresa a tu sitio, presiona click derecho -> inspeccionar y buscar con el inspector la parte donde iria la imagen, cuando la encuentres revisa que ruta te retorna, tambien puedes probar presionando "ver codigo fuente" y con control F buscar este texto <div class="site_logoSty"> ahi revisa la parte de la imagen para ver que url retorna, posiblemente no se este completando correctamente por alguna razon

Comment: muchas gracias, voy ha intentarle a ver que me resulta. Gracias.